# how to print value in textarea in jsp

Tags: jsp

```
         <% 
       out.print("<textarea name='test' id='test'value='"+uabout+"'></textarea>");

            %>
```

is not working.is there a syntax error.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this code in scripting:

```
<textarea name='test' id='test'><%=uabout %> </textarea>
```

OR 
using JSTL

```
<textarea name='test' id='test'><c:out value="${uabout}" /> </textarea>
```

Also, there is no value attribute in textarea tag.

Comment: Ouch. What happens when `uabout` contains `<b>yay, I'm bold</b>`? Always use `<c:out value="${uabout}"/>` instead.